# UISwitch switched off by user but is still programatically on

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I am experimenting with UISwitches on xcode using Swift. I have it to where there is a handful of Company names and their corresponding on and off switches. From top to bottom, if the user switches for example, "Google" Switch on, then they are able to view the chosen companies facebook and twitter. If they choose another company, once they turn that switch on for example "Samsung" , the Google switch turns off then the user is able to see Samsungs facebook and twitter page.

My issue is... from top to bottom, it works fine. Im able to see both pages from Google to samsung.  But if I go from samsung back to Google, the google switch is on but it still shows samsung's pages. But, if I switch the saumsung switch on,off then go to google, it works fine.

My assumption is that while the switch visually looks off once another switch is turned on from bottom to top, it is still programmatically on

I'm wondering if people have had a similar issue. If not, I hope this helps those in the future if they find themselves in a similar situation

Here is my main view Controller

```
import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var GoogleSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var SamsungSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var FordSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var ToyotaSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var SquareEnixSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var ABCBankSwitch: UISwitch!

var Google: Bool = false
var Samsung: Bool = false
var Ford: Bool = false
var Toyota:Bool = false
var SquareEnix :Bool = false
var ABCBank :Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 //   ABCBankSwitch.addTarget(self, action: Selector("switchIsChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func ActiveGoogle(sender: UISwitch) {

      if sender.on == true
        {
            GoogleSwitch.on = true
            SamsungSwitch.on = false
            ToyotaSwitch.on = false
            SquareEnixSwitch.on = false
            ABCBankSwitch.on = false
            Google = true

   // GoogleSwitch.on = true


    }
  else
   { Google = false
    sender.on = false
    }

   // sender.on  = false
}

@IBAction func ActiveSamsung(sender: UISwitch) {

 if sender.on == true
      {
            GoogleSwitch.on = false
            SamsungSwitch.on = true
            FordSwitch.on = false
            ToyotaSwitch.on = false
            SquareEnixSwitch.on = false
            ABCBankSwitch.on = false
            Samsung = true

    }
   else

    {sender.on = false
        Samsung = false}

}

@IBAction func ActiveFord(sender: UISwitch) {
  if sender.on == true
    {Ford = true
        GoogleSwitch.on = false
        SamsungSwitch.on = false
        FordSwitch.on  = true
        ToyotaSwitch.on = false
        SquareEnixSwitch.on = false
        ABCBankSwitch.on = false
    }
   else
  { if sender.on == false {
    Ford = false}

}
}

@IBAction func ActiveToyota(sender: UISwitch) {
   if sender.on == true
    { Toyota = true
        GoogleSwitch.on = false
        SamsungSwitch.on = false
        FordSwitch.on = false
        ToyotaSwitch.on = true
        SquareEnixSwitch.on = false
        ABCBankSwitch.on = false
    }
    else
    { Toyota = false}
}
@IBAction func ActiveEnix(sender: UISwitch) {
if sender.on == true
    { SquareEnix = true
        GoogleSwitch.on = false
        SamsungSwitch.on = false
        FordSwitch.on = false
        ToyotaSwitch.on = false
        //SquareEnixSwitch.on = true
        ABCBankSwitch.on = false
    }
    else
    { SquareEnix = false
   // sender.on = false
    }
}

@IBAction func ActiveABC(sender: UISwitch) {
  if sender.on == true
    { ABCBank = true
        ABCBankSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
        GoogleSwitch.on = false
        SamsungSwitch.on = false
        FordSwitch.on = false
        ToyotaSwitch.on = false
        SquareEnixSwitch.on = false


        }
    }
else
{
    ABCBankSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    ABCBank = false
   // sender.on = false

  }

}

}
```

here is my FacebookViewController. (not putting the twitter on as it is almost identical to the facebook one)

```
 import UIKit

 class FacebookViewController: UIViewController{
  var webAddress: String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var CompanyFB: UIWebView!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let myCompany: ViewController = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! ViewController

    let showGoogle: Bool = myCompany.Google
    let showSamsung: Bool = myCompany.Samsung
    let showFord: Bool = myCompany.Ford
    let showToyota: Bool = myCompany.Toyota
    let showEnix: Bool = myCompany.SquareEnix
    let showBank:Bool = myCompany.ABCBank


    if showGoogle  {
        webAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/Google/"
        //myCompany.GoogleSwitch.on = false  had this to test. either way is still doesnt work

      //  CompanyFB.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: webAddress)!))
    }

    if showSamsung  {
        webAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/SamsungUSA"
       // myCompany.SamsungSwitch.on = false

      //  CompanyFB.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: webAddress)!))
    }

     if showFord  {
        webAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/ford/"

      //  CompanyFB.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: webAddress)!))
    }

    if showToyota {
        webAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/toyota"


       // CompanyFB.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: webAddress)!))
    }
   if  showEnix  {
       webAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/SquareEnix"

    }

 if showBank  {
        webAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/ABC-Bank-132047286857188/"


    }

 CompanyFB.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: webAddress)!))


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't keeping your separate booleans in sync with your switches.  Consider this code:

```
@IBAction func ActiveGoogle(sender: UISwitch) {    
    if sender.on == true {
        GoogleSwitch.on = true
        SamsungSwitch.on = false
        ToyotaSwitch.on = false
        SquareEnixSwitch.on = false
        ABCBankSwitch.on = false
        Google = true
    }
    else { 
        Google = false
        sender.on = false
    }
}
```

If I change the "Google" switch then then `Google` variable will be set to true/false accordingly.  This code also turns off all of the other switches, but it doesn't change the boolean associated variables.  So, if after selecting Google I then select "Samsung", the Google switch will be turned off but the `Google` variable will still be true.

You could use a computed property rather than the separate booleans:

```
var Google: Bool {
    return self.GoogleSwitch.on
}
```

and so on.

Also, by convention variables and functions should start with a lower case letter, so it should be `var google` and `func activateGoogle`

Comment: Thank you so much. Still trying to figure out the shortcuts. Your explanation was easy to understand as well. added the return.self... to all of them and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here, some unrelated to your problem, but I'll comment on them as well so you can improve as a coder.

1) Convention for Swift dictates that you name variables and methods starting with a lower case letter. So `GoogleSwitch` should be `googleSwitch` etc. Also, try and be descriptive with the names. In your `FacebookViewController` you have a variable `myCompany` for the `ViewController` class. First, the class should be called something like `MyCompanyViewController` so you know which view controller it is. And then the `myCompany` variable could be called `myCompanyViewController`. `CompanyFB` should be something like `companyFBWebView`.

2) You can really simply your code a lot here. Use a single `IBAction` for all of the switches. A common problem (which may be an issue here), is when you copy and paste controls in Interface Builder, it sometimes will copy the actions assigned as well, and then you add another, so it calls two methods each time it's switched. By using a single method, you save a tonne of duplicated code and avoid this problem.

Your entire first `ViewController` class can be condensed to this (then connect all of your switches to the same `IBOutlet` `switchToggled:`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var googleSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var samsungSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var fordSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var toyotaSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var squareEnixSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var abcBankSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func switchToggled(sender: UISwitch) {
        // Remember the state of the triggered switch because we're about to turn it off
        let newState: Bool = sender.on

        googleSwitch.on = false
        samsungSwitch.on = false
        fordSwitch.on = false
        toyotaSwitch.on = false
        squareEnixSwitch.on = false
        abcBankSwitch.on = false

        // Restore the state of the switch
        sender.on = newState
    }
}
```

3) Avoid using duplicate variables for the same thing, the Bool for Google etc should be the same as the switch, so just use the `switch.on` value. Edit: (or as Paulw11 mentioned, use a calculated property).

4) When using an `if` to test a variable state, or multiple variable states as you're doing in the `FacebookViewController` class, when only one possible case should happen, use `else if` instead of multiple `if`'s. In your case, you're triggering two or more cases at once (due to your other bugs). If you used `else if` clauses, you'd only ever trigger one and you likely would have narrowed down your other bug earlier.

```
    if showGoogle {
        webAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/Google/"
    }
    else if showSamsung {
        webAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/SamsungUSA/"
    }
    ...
```

5) Expanding on #4 you could change this to make use of Swift's powerful `enum` features.

```
import UIKit

class FacebookViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Company: String {
        case Google = "https://www.facebook.com/Google/"
        case Samsung = "https://www.facebook.com/SamsungUSA/"
        case Ford = "https://www.facebook.com/ford/"
        case Toyota = "https://www.facebook.com/toyota/"
        case SquareEnix = "https://www.facebook.com/SquareEnix/"
        case ABCBank = "https://www.facebook.com/ABC-Bank-132047286857188/"
    }

    var company: Company = .Google // Default to Google

    @IBOutlet weak var companyFBWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let myCompanyViewController: ViewController = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! ViewController

        if myCompanyViewController.googleSwitch.on {
            company = .Google
        }
        else if myCompanyViewController.samsungSwitch.on {
            company = .Samsung
        }
        else if myCompanyViewController.fordSwitch.on {
            company = .Ford
        }
        else if myCompanyViewController.toyotaSwitch.on {
            company = .Toyota
        }
        else if myCompanyViewController.squareEnixSwitch.on {
            company = .SquareEnix
        }
        else if myCompanyViewController.abcBankSwitch.on {
            company = .ABCBank
        }

        if let url = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: company.rawValue)) {
            companyFBWebView.loadRequest(url)
        }
    }
}
```

6) In Swift, avoid using `!` like the plague. Ideally you'll only use it for `IBOutlet`'s and other cases you know for certain a value exists. The line `let myCompanyViewController: ViewController = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! ViewController` is likely to crash in some cases. Possibly due to timing issues, or other changes you may make to the code down the road. Safer to check the options with `if let` and handle the error gracefully.

7) I just noticed another issue as I was proofreading. Anytime* you `override` a method from a super class, make sure you also call the super's version. So your `viewWillAppear(animated:)` etc calls need to call the super version or you can get really weird, hard to track down bugs.

- I put a star on Anytime in #7 because there are some cases where you intentionally don't want to call the super method, but those are rare and you'll know it when the time comes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your IBActions are hooked up to the ValueChanged event, and you expect them to fire in two instances: when you change the switch by touching it; or when you change the value of the `on` property.

If so, the problem is that the event does not fire in the second case, only the first. Therefore, once `Google` is set to true, the only way it gets set back to false is by touching the switch to off.

Since your model only wants one switch to be on, you could instead have one variable containing the switch that should be on. When you touch a switch, just update that one variable and redisplay all of them. Using an `enum` for this variable would be helpful. Along the lines of:

```
    enum Switches {
        case None
        case Google
        case Samsung
    }

    var onSwitch = Switches.None
```

Then code in each IBAction along the lines of:

```
@IBAction func ActiveGoogle(sender: UISwitch) {
      if sender.on == true {
          onSwitch = Switches.Google
          updateSwitches()
      }
}
```

And `updateSwitches` looks like:

```
func updateSwitches() {
    GoogleSwitch.on = (onSwitch == Switches.Google)
    SamsungSwitch.on = (onSwitch == Switches.Samsung)
}
```